# Namespace prefix in C#

Tags: c#, namespaces

I can already do:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
Button b;
```

or:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Button b;
```

but I would like to do:

```
using System.Windows;
Forms.Button b;
```

(because Button is ambiguous with another namespace, and typing System.Windows.Forms.Button is too long).

However this gives me an error, how can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A namespace alias perhaps:

```
using Forms = System.Windows.Forms;
```

The "using System.Windows" is now superfluous unless you use classes in that namespace.

Comment: @AdamRalph: Maybe not in the OP's context.

Comment: @Cerebrus - so I made sure to have an unless disclosure